# wordpress action hook for new post not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin that inserts custom meta in the database, right after the article is published but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my piece of code that goes into the main plugin file:

```
function example($post_ID)
{
   ?>

   <!-- testing -->

   <?php

    $friends = 'email@domain.com';
    mail($friends, "Blog Post", 'New blog post has been submitted.');
    return $post_ID;
}
add_filter('publish_post', 'example');
```

This doesn't put my 'testing' comment code nowhere in page source after the article is published and I'm not receiveing any email.

Tried with add_filter and add_action, but none of them works.

Adding an action to 'wp-head', works.

Comment: `publish_post` is an action hook, so you need to use add_action. It is common practice to do database queries etc. based on submitted data and then redirect the user to a new page, preventing accidental resubmissions that can happen otherwise if the user refreshes the page. So this might be what Wordpress does, in which case you would not expect to see your comment in the source code. As for mail, try it separately to make sure it works. Could have to do with server configuration or something. In the end you might want to use `wp_mail` btw but it doesn't matter here.

Comment: thanks alot! indeed, the mail didn't worked... Silly of me that I didn't verified that in the first place. Some said that add_filter should be use, others add_action, and that confused me. Ok, so I try to submit a query, but the table doesn't seem to change. Is there a way to debug it? trying to echo anything obviously doesn't work...

Comment: You can debug as you normally would do it, with echo, print_r etc. - just write `exit;` right after. This way, you will not be redirected any further and can simply edit your code and refresh the page until you have it working. As for hook versus filter it is kind of obvious once you know what a filter is and what an action is. Thumb rule: if you need to modify a value and pass it back to Wordpress, you need a filter. If you don't need to modify a value that Wordpress is working with, you should use an action. Searching on Google you will find out that publish_post is an action hook.

Comment: got it! I think that this forum post is quite misleading: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add_action-with-publish_post thanks again for clear and straight responses to my questions!